# ddply with only certain values of splitting variable

Tags: r, plyr

Is it possible to return ddply results for only certain values of the splitting variable? For example, with the dataframe `example`:

```
example <- structure(list(shape = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("circle", "square", "triangle"
), class = "factor"), property = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("color", 
"intensity", "size"), class = "factor"), value = structure(c(5L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("3", 
"5", "6", "7", "blue", "green", "red"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("shape", 
"property", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

which looks like this

```
    shape     property  value
1   circle    color     blue
2   circle    size      5
3   circle    intensity 3
4   circle    color     blue
5   square    intensity 7
6   square    size      3
7   square    color     blue
8   square    color     green
9   square    color     green
10  triangle  color     red
11  triangle  intensity 7
12  triangle  size      6
13  triangle  color     green
14  triangle  color     blue
```

I want to return a dataframe containing the number of each shape that has a certain color, which would be something like this:

```
    shape    property  blue green   red
1   circle   color     2    0       0
2   square   color     1    2       0
3   triangle color     1    1       1
```

However, I can't seem to get this to return properly! I've gotten part of the way using something like this:

```
ColorSummary <- ddply(example,.(shape,property="color"), function(example) summary(example$value))
```

But this is returning a dataframe with columns for all of the other unique `value` (from the properties `size` and `intensity`, which I do not want):

```
    shape     property      3   5   6   7   blue    green   red
1   circle    color         1   1   0   0   2       0       0
2   square    NA            1   0   0   1   1       2       0
3   triangle  NA            0   0   1   1   1       1       1
```

What am I doing wrong - is there a way to return a dataframe like the first result that I showed?

Also, while this is a small and fast example, my "real" data are much bigger and take a long time to calculate. Does the speed of ddply improve by limiting to only `property="color"`?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers so far! Unfortunately for me, I oversimplified the situation and I'm not sure if the `dcast` solution will work for me. Let me explain - I am actually working with a dataframe `example2`:

```
example2 <- structure(list(factory = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), shape = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("circle", 
"square", "triangle"), class = "factor"), property = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("color", "intensity", "size"), class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("3", "5", "6", "7", 
    "blue", "green", "red"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("factory", 
"shape", "property", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

and I am trying to split by both `factory` and `shape`. I have a messy solution using `ddply`:

```
ColorSummary2 <- ddply(example2,.(factory,shape,property="color"), function(example2) summary(example2$value))
```

which gives

```
    factory shape   property    3   5   6   7   blue    green   red
1   A   circle  color   1   1   0   0   2   0   0
2   A   square  NA  1   0   0   1   1   2   0
3   A   triangle    NA  0   0   1   1   1   1   1
4   B   circle  NA  1   1   0   0   1   0   0
```

but what I would like to return is this (sorry for the messy table, I have trouble formatting tables on here):

```
    factory shape   property        blue    green   red
1   A   circle      color           2       0       0
2   A   square      NA              1       2       0
3   A   triangle    NA              1       1       1   
4   B   circle      NA              1       0       0
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT 2:** Sorry for all of the edits, I oversimplified my situation way too much. Here is a more complex dataframe that is closer to my real example. This one has a column `state`, which I do not want to use for splitting. I can do this (messily) with ddply, but can I ignore `state` using dcast?

```
example3 <- structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CA", "FL"
), class = "factor"), factory = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), shape = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("circle", 
"square", "triangle"), class = "factor"), property = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("color", "intensity", "size"), class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("3", "5", "6", "7", 
    "blue", "green", "red"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("state", 
"factory", "shape", "property", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Comment: The package `reshape2` might be better for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dcast` from `reshape2`:

```
dcast(...~value,data=subset(example,property=='color'))
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
     shape property blue green red
1   circle    color    2     0   0
2   square    color    1     2   0
3 triangle    color    1     1   1
```

#### EDIT

using the second data set example:

```
dcast(...~value,data=subset(example2,property=='color'))
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  factory    shape property blue green red
1       A   circle    color    2     0   0
2       A   square    color    1     2   0
3       A triangle    color    1     1   1
4       B   circle    color    1     0   0
```

Comment: Thanks agstudy, that works perfectly for the example I gave. However, I tried to simplify my example to make it easy. Unfortunately, I'm also splitting by another variable, which is why I was trying ddply. I will edit my question above to show the more complex case that I'm trying. Is there a way to do this new case using dcast?

Comment: Thank you so much, agstudy!  I really appreciate your help. Can you tell me if there is a way to tell dcast which columns to "split" by? For example, can I indicate the "factory" and "shape" columns only? The problem is that I am working with a much larger dataframe that has other columns, so the dcast solution isn't counting the factories and shapes properly.  For example, imagine if I had another column "state", dcast will give me values for state/factory/shape when instead I just want factory/shape. I hope that makes sense, if not I can add another example dataframe.  Thanks again!

Comment: dear agstudy, I updated my original question with a new dataframe showing a column that I do not want to use for splitting (state)

Comment: One workaround is to make new dataframes containing only grouping columns of interest, but ideally I would like to do this with just my original dataframe.  Thanks again agstudy for your help.